# GLPI DEPLOY: Web access to the files directory, should not be allowed

Tags: php, iis, windows-server

I'm trying to install GLPI on a Windows Server 2016 server, with IIS10 and PHP 7.2.
I have given the modification permissions to the users: IIS_IUSRS, Users, IUSR, NETWORK SERVICE (permissions to modify the glpi folder).

During the verification of the requirements, the following message is returned to me:
"Web access to the files directory should not be allowed but this cannot be checked automatically on this instance.
 Make sure acces to error log file is forbidden; otherwise review .htaccess file and web server configuration."

Any suggestions on how to solve?

Thank you...

Comment: Could you please tell me what kinds of application pool identity you have used now? Network service or application pool identity.  Could you please tell me which kind folder doesn't has the permission?

Comment: I, I use Network service: https://imgur.com/a/CehoPiw
I set the permissions of the following users: IUSR, NETWORK SERVICE, Users, IIS_IUSRS, permission: modify, read, Write.

Thank you for support.

Comment: Anyone who can suggest me some solution?